# Code duplication reduces effective cache size

Tags: c++, cpu-cache

I'm reading a presentation from Scott Mayor, he mentiones this line:

> Down side of inlining: Code duplication reduces effective cache size

I am not seeing how code duplication has anything to do with effective cache size

Comment: If a frequently used function is not inlined, then its code exists in a single location in memory, which will be frequently hit and hence likely to be in cache most of the time. On the other hand, if it is inlined, many copies of the code will exist in different locations and hence the cache is not as useful.

Comment: Makes perfect sense don't know how I missed that. Thanks

Comment: @cicada should be answer not comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Duplicating code means that the same instructions are duplicated on consecutive memory addresses instead of having one single copy of those instructions in the body of a loop. That means that many cache lines are filled with the same content instead of just a few. As those instructions are frequently accessed (once per loop run) they are likely not leaving the cache, so other code (or data if cache is unified) must leave, which wouldn't happen if there were less number of frequently accessed instructions filling cache entries.